ASP.NET webform with HTMX brings back full page in response
I am updating old asp.net webform application using HTMX so that I can get the SPA support (sort of). I have a simple bloglist/Newslist page where I am listing 8-10 blog items and using paging to navigate through pages which work fine to further enhance page experience I used HTMX so that it will only render the bloglist/newslist element when user navigates through pages using paging on the page.
It work and changes the page url also when I click on different pages however it bring back full page in response which results in nested form elements inside the target element. on frontend it looks nice however you see the nested elements only when you inspect the page of view page source. Some suggested to use user control for bloglisting which I did however it had the same result.
Below is the code of the Page, User Control and .cs file may be i am doing something wrong.
May be some webform expert may notice the issue or it can be the asp.net architecture which does that.
.aspx page
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PaginationHTMXUC.aspx.cs" Inherits="en_PaginationHTMXUC" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/en/UserControls/ucNewsList.ascx" TagName="NewsListControl" TagPrefix="ucNewslist" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <%--<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.4.0"></script>--%>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.12"></script>
    
        <style>
        .active {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    
        .disabled {
            pointer-events: none;
            color: #ccc;
        }
    
    #blog-list {
        transition: opacity 1.3s ease, transform 1.3s ease;
    }
    
    #blog-list.htmx-request {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-1);
    }
    </style>
    
    </head>
    
    <body id="body">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="main-content">
                <div id="blog-list" hx-target="this" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-get="BlogList.aspx?page=1" hx-push-url="true">
                    <!-- User control initial load -->
                   <ucNewslist:NewsListControl ID="newslist" runat="server" /> 
                </div>
            </div>
             
        </form>
    </body>
    
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('htmx:beforeRequest', function (event) {
                document.getElementById('blog-list').classList.add('htmx-request');
            });
    
            document.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', function (event) {
                document.getElementById('blog-list').classList.remove('htmx-request');
            });
        </script>
    </html>

.CS file
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    
    
    public partial class en_PaginationHTMXUC : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       
    
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack || Request.Headers["HX-Request"] == "true")
            {
               // BindBlogs();
            }
        }
    
       
    }

ucNewsList.ascx
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ucNewsList.ascx.cs" Inherits="en_UserControls_ucNewsList" %>
    
    <ul>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptBlog" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <h2><%# Eval("NewsHeading") %></h2>
                    <%--                                <p><%# Eval("NewsHeading") %></p>
                                    <small><%# Eval("NewsDate", "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}") %></small>--%>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
    
    <div>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkFirst" runat="server" hx-push-url="true" hx-get='<%# "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=1" %>'>First</asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkPrev" runat="server" hx-push-url="true" hx-get='<%# "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + (CurrentPage - 1) %>'>Previous</asp:HyperLink>
    
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptPages" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkPage" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + Eval("PageIndex") %>'
                    Text='<%# Eval("PageText") %>' CssClass='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("PageIndex")) == CurrentPage ? "active" : "" %>'
                    hx-push-url="true" hx-get='<%# "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + Eval("PageIndex") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkNext" runat="server" hx-push-url="true" hx-get='<%# "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + (CurrentPage + 1) %>'>Next</asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkLast" runat="server" hx-push-url="true" hx-get='<%# "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + TotalPages %>'>Last</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>

ucNewsList.ascx.cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    
    
    public partial class en_UserControls_ucNewsList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        private int PageSize = 1;
    
        public int CurrentPage
        {
            get
            {
                int page;
                if (!int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"], out page))
                {
                    page = 1;
                }
                return page;
            }
        }
    
        public int TotalPages
        {
            get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)TotalRecords / PageSize); }
        }
    
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack || Request.Headers["HX-Request"] == "true")
            {
                BindBlogs();
            }
        }
    
        private void BindBlogs()
        {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetPagedNews", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", CurrentPage);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", PageSize);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    
                        conn.Open();
                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            da.Fill(dt);
                            // Response.Write("Rows Count: " + dt.Rows.Count + "<br/>");
                            rptBlog.DataSource = dt;
                            rptBlog.DataBind();
    
                            TotalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Value);
                           // Response.Write("Total Records: " + TotalRecords + "<br/>");
                        }
    
                        conn.Close();
                        BindPaging();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message + "<br/>");
                }
            }
        }
    
    
    
    
        private void BindPaging()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("PageIndex");
            dt.Columns.Add("PageText");
    
            int startPageIndex = Math.Max(1, CurrentPage - 5);
            int endPageIndex = Math.Min(TotalPages, CurrentPage + 5);
    
            for (int i = startPageIndex; i <= endPageIndex; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(i, i);
            }
    
            rptPages.DataSource = dt;
            rptPages.DataBind();
    
            // Add HTMX attributes dynamically in code-behind
            if (CurrentPage > 1)
            {
                lnkFirst.NavigateUrl = "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=1";
                lnkFirst.Attributes["hx-get"] = "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=1";
                lnkFirst.Attributes["hx-target"] = "#blog-list";
                lnkFirst.Attributes["hx-push-url"] = "true";
    
                lnkPrev.NavigateUrl = "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + (CurrentPage - 1);
                lnkPrev.Attributes["hx-get"] = "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + (CurrentPage - 1);
                lnkPrev.Attributes["hx-target"] = "#blog-list";
                lnkPrev.Attributes["hx-push-url"] = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                lnkPrev.CssClass = "disabled";
                lnkFirst.CssClass = "disabled";
            }
    
            if (CurrentPage < TotalPages)
            {
                lnkNext.NavigateUrl = "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + (CurrentPage + 1);
                lnkNext.Attributes["hx-get"] = "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + (CurrentPage + 1);
                lnkNext.Attributes["hx-target"] = "#blog-list";
                lnkNext.Attributes["hx-push-url"] = "true";
    
                lnkLast.NavigateUrl = "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + TotalPages;
                lnkLast.Attributes["hx-get"] = "PaginationHTMXUC.aspx?page=" + TotalPages;
                lnkLast.Attributes["hx-target"] = "#blog-list";
                lnkLast.Attributes["hx-push-url"] = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                lnkNext.CssClass = "disabled";
                lnkLast.CssClass = "disabled";
            }
        }
    }


You can see in the screenshot that response get additional elements and adds them to the target element rather than only getting the only contents of #blog-list. I am not sure if this is suppose to be like this or it can be fixed.
Front en view as i am only showing 1 blog for testing purpose
Page 1

Page 4


Looks like htmx is swapping out at the form level, so try retargeting the response to overwrite the form1 element, and make sure the swap strategy is outerHTML (as default is innerHTML)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class en_PaginationHTMXUC : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack || Request.Headers["HX-Request"] == "true")
        {
           Response.Headers.Add("HX-Retarget", "form1");
           Response.Headers.Add("HX-Reswap", "outerHTML");
        }
    }
   
}


Issue was resolved however in actual code i have multiple js files which need to reinitialize otherwise animation or desired functionality doesn't work.. SO far i didnt find a way to make it work so all the .js files are reloaded and so animation will work
